# Python Black for Atom not formatting on Apple M1 chip

Tags: python

I have a pretty simple file I'm trying to reformat, `itsadate.py`, and when I run the command `black itsadate.py` from a terminal I get the following error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/black/__init__.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002
): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/black/__init__.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, b
ut is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/__init__.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try reinstalling Black? Where the error message says `incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')`, do you understand what that means? Also, what does this question have to do with Atom?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Reinstalling black worked! Thank you. And yes, I understand what that means, I just didn't think that would be fixed by reinstalling it since it had previously worked on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this problem. Here is my solution, maybe it helps someone.

I've migrated from Mac Intel to Mac M1, and I've migrated all my projects.
I've used black library in prehook.
The problem was in Intel .venv/ and incorrect paths to intel lib. Commit prehook has tried to use M1 libraries:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/my_user/my_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/black/__init__.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/my_user/my_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/black/__init__.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/my_user/my_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/black/__init__.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/my_user/my_project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/black/__init__.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

How to solve this problem?

1. Uninstall Intel brew with script from https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew
2. Install brew for M1 with this script $ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
3. remove old (Intel) .venv/

```
sudo rm -rf /you/way/to_you/.venv/
```

4. recreate it again for M1

```
python -m venv .venv
```